# React autocomplete textbox

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, textbox

```
const champions=[
    {label: 'Ahri'},
    {label: 'Amumu'}
]
```

So how do I select the value of that textbox?
Tried with event.target.favChamps.value but apparently doesn't select anything, is it because those are items and not regular text?

```
<Stack spacing={3} > 
            <Autocomplete multiple id="tags-outlined" options={champions} sx={{width: "48%"}} defaultValue={[champions[0]]} filterSelectedOptions renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField {...params} label="Favorite Champions"  name="favChamps" onChange={championPool} placeholder="Choose 3 champions max." size="small"/>
            )}/>
        </Stack>
```

Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: upvote . . . . .

Comment: Please add code using text instead of images.

Comment: Done? Any idea? kinda urgent :/